# How to upload image to folder and insert to database In CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Need to upload image into folder and insert filename to MySQL and image name should be unique.
My Controller code is:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{  
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/gallery/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image_file');
    $title=$this->input->post('title');
    $value=array(
        'title' => $title,
        'image_name' => $new_image_name,
        'crop_name' => $crop_image_name
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
public function uploadImageFile() //gallery insert
 { 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $new_image_name = time() . str_replace(str_split(' ()\\/,:*?"<>|'), '', 
    $_FILES['image_file']['name']);
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/gallery/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
    $config['file_name'] = $new_image_name;
    $config['max_size']  = '0';
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';
    $config['$min_width'] = '0';
    $config['min_height'] = '0';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload('image_file');
    $title=$this->input->post('title');
    $value=array('title'=>$title,'image_name'=>
    $new_image_name,'crop_name'=>$crop_image_name);}
```